# filesystem loop when building my rust project with docker

Tags: docker, rust, filesystems

I have a rust repository looking like:

```
.
├── bot
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── cargo.toml
│   ├── build.rs
│   ├── proto
│   │   └── status.proto
│   └── src
│       └── [project source code files]
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Here is the build.rs:

```rs
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tonic_build::configure()
        .build_server(false)
        .protoc_arg("--experimental_allow_proto3_optional")
        .compile(&["proto/status.proto"], &["proto"])?;
    Ok(())
}
```

And the dockerfile:

```
# Use the official Rust image as the base image
FROM rust:latest

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR .

# Copy the source code
COPY bot/ .

# Build the application in release mode
RUN cargo build --release

# Expose the port your application uses
EXPOSE 8080

# Set the unbuffered environment variable
ENV RUST_BACKTRACE "1"

# Run the binary
CMD ["./target/release/bot"]
```

I can build it without issues using `cargo build --release`, but when I try to build it with docker I get a filesystem loop:

```
 => => # /rtc0/alarmtimer.0.auto/subsystem/devices/40000000.pci/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.0/driver/0000:00:01.0/virtio0/subsystem/devices/virtio2/bloc
 => => # k/vda/vda1/subsystem/loop5/bdi/subsystem/0:175/subsystem points to an ancestor /sys/class/devlink/amba:20060000.pl061--platform:gpio-keys
 => => # /supplier/subsystem/devices/20050000.pl031/rtc/rtc0/alarmtimer.0.auto/subsystem/devices/40000000.pci/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.0/driver/0000:
 => => # 00:01.0/virtio0/subsystem/devices/virtio2/block/vda/vda1/subsystem/loop5/bdi/subsystem                                                   
 => => # warning: File system loop found: /sys/                                                                                                   
 => => # [output clipped, log limit 2MiB reached]
```

What could cause that filesystem loop and how should I fix it? When trying on other systems (macos, linux), I keep getting it.

Comment: `WORKDIR .` sets the working directory to the current working directory, which is probably the filesystem root `/`.  Do you want to pick a different directory?  Something like `WORKDIR /app` is pretty typical.